# How to get the id of an element with its index using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using `.index()` we can get the position or index of an element. Now i want to know that
can we get the element's `id` using its index ?

An Example,

```
<ul id="unOrderedList">
<li id="gears"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="tyres"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="rear"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="mirror"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="charger"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="port"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
<li id="list"><a class="links" href="#">Click here!</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the above mark up, if i want to know 4th `<li>` id means, how shall it do it with jquery?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the index ahead of time, just use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, like so:

```
$("#unOrderedList li[id^=list]:eq(3)").attr("id")
```

or use the [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filter method:

```
$("#unOrderedList li").eq(3).attr("id")
```

EDIT: I'm guessing that this is what you're after:

```
$("#unOrderedList li a.links").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/ULqbr/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#unOrderedList li').eq(Index).attr( 'id' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('ul li a').click(function(index){
          $(li).eq(Index).attr( 'id' )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $('#unOrderedList li:eq(3)').attr("id");
```